# Why is my blur function in CS50's filter(less) (PSET 4) not returning the correct values?

Tags: c, cs50

currently stuck on CS50's PSET 4 filter less. To create the blur function, I came up with 9 possible cases of where a pixel could in an image (eg in 1st row and 1st column). However, when I used check50 to check my code, the values the function returns are different from the expected values. I have looked through my code multiple times but I can't quite see where the problem lies and was hoping for a second pair of eyes to help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Copy 2D image array into a new array to work with
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Determine case and respond accordingly
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // CASE 1: Pixel is not in 1st/last row AND not in 1st/LAST column
            if (0 < j < width - 1 && 0 < i < height - 1 )
            {
                int R1 = round((copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed)/9.0);
                int G1 = round((copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen)/9.0);
                int B1 = round((copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue)/9.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R1;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G1;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B1;
            }
            // CASE 2: Pixel in 1st row, 1st column
            else if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                int R2 = round((copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                int B2 = round((copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                int G2 = round((copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R2;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G2;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B2;
            }
            // CASE 3: Pixel in 1st row, NOT 1ST/LAST COLUMN
            else if (i == 0 && 0 < j < width - 1)
            {
                int R3 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                int G3 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
                int B3 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R3;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G3;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B3;
            }
            // CASE 4: PIXEL IN 1ST ROW, LAST COLUMN
            else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1)
            {
                int R4 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                int B4 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                int G4 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R4;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G4;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B4;
            }
            // CASE 5: PIXEL NOT IN 1ST/LAST ROW, IN 1ST COLUMN
            else if (0 < i < height - 1 && j == 0)
            {
                int R5 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                int G5 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                int B5 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R5;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G5;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B5;
            }
            // CASE 6: PIXEL IN LAST ROW, 1ST COLUMN
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0)
            {
                int R6 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                int B6 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                int G6 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R6;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G6;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B6;
            }
            // CASE 7: Pixel IN LAST ROW, LAST COLUMN
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1)
            {
                int R7 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed)/4.0);
                int B7 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue)/4.0);
                int G7 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen)/4.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R7;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G7;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B7;
            }
            // CASE 8: PIXEL IN LAST ROW, NOT LAST / 1ST COLUMN
            else if (i == height - 1 && 0 < j < width - 1)
            {
                int R8 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                int G8 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
                int B8 = round((copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R8;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G8;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B8;
            }
            // CASE 9: PIXEL IN LAST COLUMN, NOT 1ST / LAST ROW
            else if (0 < i < height - 1 && j == width - 1 )
            {
                int R9 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed)/6.0);
                int G9 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue)/6.0);
                int B9 = round((copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen)/6.0);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = R9;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = G9;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = B9;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I thought that the problem was due to using the same variable names to store the new RGB values so I created unique variable names to store the RGB values for each of the 9 cases (eg. R1 R2 R3 ...). However, this was not the case.

Comment: Don't spam tags please.

Comment: Take 5 minutes break to read [How to Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Edit] your question to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is that relational operators don't work how you hope.

Specifically; for a condition like `0 < i < height` the compiler evaluates it from left to right, like `(0 < i) < height`, where the first part becomes true or false and the second part is comparing against true of false and not comparing against `i` (like `TRUE < height`).

To fix this, you have to use a boolean operator between the relational operators, like `(0 < i) && (i < height)`.

As an alternative; you could delete all the branches and just do pixels in order; like:

```
    // Do top left pixel
    // Do middle pixels on top row
    for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {
    }
    // Do top right pixel

    // Do middle rows
    for (int i = 1; i < height-1; i++) {
        // Do pixel on left edge
        // Do middle pixels
        for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {
        }
        // Do pixel on right edge
     }

    // Do bottom left pixel
    // Do middle pixels on bottom row
    for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++) {
    }
    // Do bottom right pixel
```